# With tanstack query and provide/inject, what's the actual use-case for Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, pinia, tanstack, vue-query

I like the fact that Vue gives so many options, but I am a little confused here.
Considering that:

- Tanstack's vue-query is extremely efficient and managing/caching data coming from the server
- Inject/provide is an awesome mechanism to provide "globals" that can also be reactive. It's even more awesome, as you can provide() at app-level (real global) or in sub-section of the app (with a sub-element provide()'ing). You can also provide refs.

So... what's the possible use case of using Pinia at all?

Comment: You may not need provide/inject at all if you don't deal with SSR or DI. You could use https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api with the same result, and the comparison would be Pinia vs anything else. Pinia is a convenience wrapper over Vue reactivity. A simple global state may be hard to debug, while Pinia actions are traceable in devtools.